# Why does Firefox not render border of table with empty tbody?

Tags: css, firefox, border

Firefox does not render table cell borders correctly when a table has an empty tbody.

But if you use the pseudo selector `tbody:empty {display:none;}` to hide the tbody element, everything is rendered as expected.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zeropaper/kwbd4vgz/)

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,
td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.fixed tbody:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="broken">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<hr />

<table class="fixed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Heads up for folks like me: Make sure your empty `<tbody>` tag opens & closes on the same line. Otherwise it seems the white space within will defy the `:empty` selector and prevent this trick from working. The workaround I was using was to have an empty `<tr>` tag within the `<tbody>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It most likely belongs to [Bug 409254](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=409254) and [Bug 217769](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=217769) on Firefox.

Side note: Although an empty `tbody` is valid in HTML 5, but the number of the cells in each row group should be matched (except using `colspan`) in one table.

A workaround would be drawing the borders separately on both the table and cell elements.

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate; /*changed from collapse*/
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px; /*draw bottom and left borders*/
}
th,
td {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 0; /*draw top and right borders*/
}
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwbd4vgz/1/)**

Comment: Ok, thank you for the hint. It seemed legit to me to have an empty tbody (it still is a tag). Because, yes, it may happens (in case you are filling the tbody with javascript after some user interaction).

Comment: You're welcome. I edited the answer, suggested a workaround.